# If I change my app over now to only support iOS7+ do I need to do anything to get the compatibility alerts from apple in the store?

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

Question says it all! But to see what I'm talking about, the Apple Store has a new feature instead of telling people they need to upgrade they will let people download older compatible versions!

Link:
[App Store Backwards Compatibility](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2013/09/17/apple-begins-allowing-users-running-legacy-ios-builds-to-download-older-versions-of-apps/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. As long as there is an existing version of your app on the store that supports a prior version of iOS it will be taken care of automatically.

If for some reason you *didn't* want this behaviour (perhaps your older version uses an API that no longer exists) you can disable it under *Rights & Pricing* in iTunes Connect.